# Rspec - save function not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Basic database methods like "save", which worked previously, are not working anymore, and I can't find existing questions addressing why.

Running bundle exec rails spec/ throws an undefined save for nil:Nilclass error for many locations.

> c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:242:in 'module_eval'
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:242:in 'subclass'
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:228:in 'describe
>   and so on...

Could it due to gem version mismatches?

My test and development databases using postgresql are up to date and fully migrated.

I made sure to have

```
config.include Capybara::DSL
```

in my spec_helper.rb file.

```
user_spec.rb
.
.
.
describe "with mixed case" do
        let(:mixed_case_email) { "FooBaR@GmAIL.CoM" }
        before { @user.email = mixed_case_email }

        describe "should be saved as all lower-case" do
          @user.save
          expect(@user.email).to eq mixed_case_email.downcase               
        end     

        describe "and that's already taken" do
                before { user_with_same_email = @user.dup 
                             user_with_same_email.email
                             user_with_same_email.save }
                describe "should be invalid" do                     
                    it { should_not be_valid }
                end
        end             
.
.
.
```

Comment: You can't just put random code in the middle of your Rspec code. You need to put the `user_with_same_email.email; userr_with_same_email.save` inside the context of a test.

Comment: I changed the code to the above. The save undefined method for nil:NilClass still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

"Save" method is working fine with Rspec. It has some other problem.

```
  describe 'Anything goes here ...' do
    before do
      @p = Project.create(:name => 'logtasks')
      @p.save
    end
    it { expect(@p.name).to eq 'logtasks' }
  end
```